# Is it possible that the same value multiply for another number (and its mutiple) fall to different values?

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding

Is it possible that, given a value (i.e. 44100.0f) and multiply for another (or its multiple) (i.e. 1/8 = 2/16) it gives a different value?

Example:

```
44100.0 * 1/8 != 44100.0 * 2/16
```

or

```
44100.0 * 1/8 != 44100 * 2 / 16
```

This because I do something like this:

```
float patternLength = 44100.0f;
float steps = 8.0f;
float position = 1.0f;

float stepLength = patternLength / steps;
int result = (int)std::round(position  * stepLength);
```

This gives `5513` (since it rounds `5512.5` to `5513`), but what if the result was `5512,4999999`? It will round to `5512`.

That's my trouble: I need to ensure that they take the same values, whatever the multiplied numbers (and its multiple) are.

Do I need to sum some sort of `EPSILON` before round? Or Floating Point math guarantee this to me out of the box?

Comment: "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic" https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html
The title is quite explicit, isn't it? Reading it (at the least the beginning) gives a better understanding of this kind of problems.

Comment: What is the range of the possible values? You may be lucky enough to always have numbers that are represantable as `float` without any rounding.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? You say something about taking “the same values”, but `result` is going to proceed irregularly in some cases even if `stepLength` is computed exactly. For example, if `stepLength` is 3.25, then result will be 3 (for position 1), then 7, then 10, 13, 16, 20… Sometimes it increases by 3, sometimes by 4, and this is due to your `std::round`, not due to floating-point roundings. What are the things you need to have the “same values,” and why?

Comment: @EricPostpischil that's ok! The important is that at 1/8 or at 2/16 result is the same value. The same for 3/12 or 1/4... and so on.

Comment: "what if the result was 5512,4999999? It will round to 5512." --> What is the real case where `patternLength, steps, position` that computed a value like that?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica that's the question :) Is there any situation where a multiple of some rational number can ends with different approx?

Comment: Why does code call `round()` instead of `ceil()` if `5512,4999999` should end as `5513`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica that's doesnt matter. If I use ceil, I only move the problem. Because I can have 5512,9999999...

Comment: Hmmm, when `steps` is a power of 2 , then a difference is not expected, else yes.  What are the range and value limitation of `patternLength, steps, position`?  OK to force FP math to use `double`?

Comment: nope, I'm using float not double (shouldn't be a problem here). `position` will range from 0 to 15. `steps` between 1 and 16. `patternLength` in 44100.0f * [1, 16]

Comment: @markzzz Thanks for providing the _ranges_.  Yet are the values all whole numbers or not like `pattern_length = 1.0625`and every possible `float` [1-16]? IAC, when `position / steps` is a constant ratio `n`, then `(5* position) / (5 * steps)`, although it is the same `n,` mathematically may not yield the same `result` computationally.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this assertion?

Comment: Can `step` assume *all* the values between 1 and 16 or only powers of two (and 1)?

Comment: All values..... (Whole)

Answer (score 3):

**IEEE754 Answer**

The IEEE754 floating point specification requires that the closest floating point value to an arithmetic operation is returned.

So 1.0f / 8 will be the same as 2.0f / 16 for example.

But this does **not** mean that `a * b / c` is necessarily the same as `a * (n * b) / (n * c)` for arbitrary `n`. This is due to the *associativity* of `*` and `/` being from left to right.

Of course I'm assuming that both the numerator and denominator can be represented exactly, which small whole numbers can be.

**General Answer**

In general, C++ floating point does *not* guarantee this.

Comment: `In general, C++ floating point does not guarantee this.` lol :) Nice! So the only solution is to add an EPSILON? This will solve the issue?

Comment: @markzzz: I salute you if you need to target a platform that doesn't have IEEE754 floating point. Personally I'd use a static assertion to fail compilation in such cases, and code the way you have it.